# SubscribeToStreamingNotifications

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

I wants to create multiple   `SubscribeToStreamingNotifications` for multiple emails . Any thought how to implements this scenario.  Any help would be appreciable

```
if (folderResults.Folders.Count == 1)
{
     _subcriptionFolderId = folderResults.Folders[0].Id;
     _subscription = _exchangeService.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(
         new FolderId[] { _subcriptionFolderId },
         new EventType[] { EventType.Moved, EventType.Modified }
     );

     _logger.WarnFormat("SetupStreamingNotificationSubscription for Folder: {0} - ID: {1}", _mailboxFolder.FolderName, _mailboxFolder.FolderId);

     return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscription can't span the context of more the one Mailbox, you can logically group subscription into one connection I would suggest you read

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2015/11/17/ews-streaming-notifications-with-exchange-2013/

and

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458789(v=exchg.150).aspx

There is a good code sample that implements this using the EWS Managed API https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2013/04/16/ews-streaming-notification-sample/

Comment: Thanks a lot for kind help..actually I am facing issue as my code allows only one mail to migrate to office 365 clod .as per my understanding its not allowing to create another subscription for second email . .If a mail congaing multiple folder it only access single folder  .please help me out

Comment: You can subscribe to all folders in the Mailbox eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.subscribetopushnotificationsonallfolders(v=exchg.80).aspx